# Transport scheme NOT recognized: [amqp]

Tags: java, activemq-classic, amqp

Am trying to use AMQP with ActiveMQ and am getting the following error

```
Transport scheme NOT recognized: [amqp]
```

This is my code

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
        "amqp://localhost:61616");

Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Queue queue = session.createQueue("somequeue");

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

    // We will send a small text message saying 'Hello'
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setText("Publishing : New Message ");
    producer.send(message);

    connection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please note that AMQP in ActiveMQ is implemented in the Server only and not in the JMS client. The JMS client actually implements the "default" OpenWire protocol (and the intra-JVM transport).

You should use some other client library to communicate with ActiveMQ using AMQP, such as [Apache QPID](http://qpid.apache.org/proton/) which is [recommended by ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html#AMQP-AMQP1.0clientlibrary).

Comment: Thanks! But can u tell me how to use that?
I tried this but still same error
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new AMQConnectionFactory("amqp://guest:guest@clientid/test?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'");

Comment: Check out this unit test for AMQP in ActiveMQ trunk: https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/activemq/trunk/activemq-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/JMSClientTest.java?r=1406466&r=1414990

It does this setup using qpid client libs.

Comment: Thanks for the working code. one clarification. I see no protocol is mentioned here i.e i dont amqp:// anywhere here. And I see 
ConnectionFactoryImpl, QueueImpl are from org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl. So does it mean that they will create on ampq connection only???

Comment: AMQP is a communication protocol just like OpenWire.
The QPID client uses AMQP and the ActiveMQ client uses OpenWire. There is no need to specify which protocol to use. In ActiveMQ you typically specify things like tcp:.. when you actually mean "OpenWire" but that implicit.

Comment: the code works locally. But when I move the Publisher and Receiver in different machines! ActiveMQ is throwing MessageNotReadableException