# amqp qpid 1.0 protocol uri format

Tags: jms, amqp, qpid

I am trying to upgrade AMQP version of my application to  1.0(QPID 0.24.0).
Currently, Connectionfactory URL is in below format.

```
amqp://guest:guest@test/test?brokerlist='tcp://ip1:5672?ssl='true'&ssl_cert_alias='cert1''
```

I have tried changing URL to below format and tried different combinations(brute force)

```
amqps://hostname:port?option=value&option2=value..
```

I am always getting below error

> Root exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied URI
>   cannot contain a User-Info section
>       at org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory.createConnectionFactories(JmsInitialContextFactory.java:142

I have no clue why I am getting this error.

Also please share if there are any tutorials for AMQP QPID 1.0.

Comment: I think the same question is dealt with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164431/communicating-with-amqp-1-0-broker-over-ssl-using-qpid  I think in your first example, you just have the single-quotes in the wrong places

Answer (score 2):

The Qpid JMS clients for AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 use different connection factory URL formats.  The url you provide

```
amqp://guest:guest@test/test?brokerlist='tcp://ip1:5672?ssl='true'&ssl_cert_alias='cert1''
```

is in the format for the AMQP 0-9-1 client.  You should follow the documentation here: http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.24.0/docs/index.html for the correct format for the AMQP 1.0 client

Translating your example I would expect something like this:

```
amqps://ip1:5672?jms.username=guest&jms.password=guest&jms.clientID=test&amqp.vhost=test&transport.keyAlias=cert1
```